# GrapheneOS backend updater repository

Tags: android-source

I am currently looking for the server-side project of the GrapheneOS updater repository on their GitHub repository. Although I thought that GrapheneOS is a completely open-source project, I am having difficulty locating this specific component. I have found the following link (https://github.com/GrapheneOS/releases.grapheneos.org), but it does not appear to be the correct resource as everything is implemented with shell.